# Angularjs pass simple string to component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm **desperately** trying to pass a simple string to an AngularJS component,
I have the following angularJS component:

**async-typeahead.componenet.js:**

```
angular.module('asyncTypeahead').component('asyncTypeahead', {
    
    templateUrl: 'static/partials/async-typeahead/async-typeahead.template.html',
    bindings: {
        pk: '=',
        object: '=',
        objectType: '@'
    },
    controller: ['$scope','$http',
        function AsyncTypeaheadController($scope, $http) {

             var self = this;


            self.getTags = function (val) {
                console.log("async-typeahead input is: " +val);
                console.log("async-typeahead object keys are: " + angular.toJson(self.object));
                
                console.log("async-typeahead type is: " + angular.toJson(self.objectType));...
```

And following html to call the component:

```
<async-typeahead object="$ctrl.actor.actor_tags" objectType={{ This is just a string }}></async-typeahead>
```

'val' is just an input from the typeahead.

I've tried `objectType={{ This is just a string }}` and  `objectType="This is just a string"` and `objectType=This is just a string` I also tried changing the binding from '=' to '@' or '>' the result is the same:

whenever I look at the console I always I get:

> async-typeahead input is: df
>
> async-typeahead object kes are: [37,43,49]
>
> async-typeahead type is: **undefined**

What am I doing wrong? How can I pass a simple string to an angularJS component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue with objectType attribute which you have used in html. Directive/Component name and its all attributes should used as "-" delimited.

### Correct code is attached below:

```
<async-typeahead object="$ctrl.actor.actor_tags" object-type="This is just a string"></async-typeahead>
```